# Placebo effect and why they work

Tags: medicine, psychology, immunity, psychoneuropharmacology

I'm just wondering how the placebo effect works on people. If a patient is given fake drugs , how does that make him better? So what if they feel more "assured", how would that help the body immunity (t cells, phagocytes, etc) fight the infection better? How does phycological emotions affect the physical aspects of our immunity? Also I've read an interesting article online showing us that placebo effect works even when you know you are given fake drugs? This really complicates my understanding. How would such a approach even work?
http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/placebo-can-work-even-know-placebo-201607079926

Comment: well for a start it helps if your remember emotions are chemical reactions occurring in the body, psychological and physical are not separate.

Comment: The paper isn't about immunity, and the answer is in the paper you cite: *Kaptchuk says placebos... can work for conditions that are defined by “self-observation” symptoms like pain, nausea, or fatigue. “People can still get a placebo response, even though they know they are on a placebo,” he adds. “You don’t need deception or concealment for many conditions to get a significant and meaningful placebo effect.* Placebos don't work on serious illnesses (they don't fight infections or cancer); they work on *perception of illness* and on the mind-body connection in illness, which is too broad.